# c# layering two arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, console, layer

I am trying to create a sort of "You sunk my battleship" game. 
So far I have two arrays:
1. The board (Table) -- the surface to play on
2. the ship (Avion) -- in this case an airplane

What I am trying to achieve is to create a 3rd array that contains the whole surface and places the plain in it.

so i have
Airplane:

```
0 0 1 0 0
1 1 1 1 1
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 1 1 1 0
```

and surface:

```
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 8 10
A 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
B 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
C 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
D 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
E 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
F 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
G 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
H 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
I 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
J 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

What I`m trying to achieve is:

```
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 8 10
A 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
B 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
C 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
D 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
E 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
F 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
G 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
H 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
I 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
J 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

int counterAvion = 0;
        int counterTable = 0;

        int[,] Table = new int[10, 10];
        int[,] Avion = new int[5, 5];
        int[,] Combined = new int[10, 10];


        // Table[][]
        //rowA
        Table[0, 0] = 0; Table[0, 1] = 0; Table[0, 2] = 0; Table[0, 3] = 0; Table[0, 4] = 0;
        Table[0, 5] = 0; Table[0, 6] = 0; Table[0, 7] = 0; Table[0, 8] = 0; Table[0, 9] = 0;
        //rowB
        Table[1, 0] = 0; Table[1, 1] = 0; Table[1, 2] = 0; Table[1, 3] = 0; Table[1, 4] = 0;
        Table[1, 5] = 0; Table[1, 6] = 0; Table[1, 7] = 0; Table[1, 8] = 0; Table[1, 9] = 0;
        //rowC
        Table[2, 0] = 0; Table[2, 1] = 0; Table[2, 2] = 0; Table[2, 3] = 0; Table[2, 4] = 0;
        Table[2, 5] = 0; Table[2, 6] = 0; Table[2, 7] = 0; Table[2, 8] = 0; Table[2, 9] = 0;
        //rowD
        Table[3, 0] = 0; Table[3, 1] = 0; Table[3, 2] = 0; Table[3, 3] = 0; Table[3, 4] = 0;
        Table[3, 5] = 0; Table[3, 6] = 0; Table[3, 7] = 0; Table[3, 8] = 0; Table[3, 9] = 0;
        //rowE
        Table[4, 0] = 0; Table[4, 1] = 0; Table[4, 2] = 0; Table[4, 3] = 0; Table[4, 4] = 0;
        Table[4, 5] = 0; Table[4, 6] = 0; Table[4, 7] = 0; Table[4, 8] = 0; Table[4, 9] = 0;
        //rowF
        Table[5, 0] = 0; Table[5, 1] = 0; Table[5, 2] = 0; Table[5, 3] = 0; Table[5, 4] = 0;
        Table[5, 5] = 0; Table[5, 6] = 0; Table[5, 7] = 0; Table[5, 8] = 0; Table[5, 9] = 0;
        //rowG
        Table[6, 0] = 0; Table[6, 1] = 0; Table[6, 2] = 0; Table[6, 3] = 0; Table[6, 4] = 0;
        Table[6, 5] = 0; Table[6, 6] = 0; Table[6, 7] = 0; Table[6, 8] = 0; Table[6, 9] = 0;
        //rowH
        Table[7, 0] = 0; Table[7, 1] = 0; Table[7, 2] = 0; Table[7, 3] = 0; Table[7, 4] = 0;
        Table[7, 5] = 0; Table[7, 6] = 0; Table[7, 7] = 0; Table[7, 8] = 0; Table[7, 9] = 0;
        //rowI
        Table[8, 0] = 0; Table[8, 1] = 0; Table[8, 2] = 0; Table[8, 3] = 0; Table[8, 4] = 0;
        Table[8, 5] = 0; Table[8, 6] = 0; Table[8, 7] = 0; Table[8, 8] = 0; Table[8, 9] = 0;
        //rowJ
        Table[9, 0] = 0; Table[9, 1] = 0; Table[9, 2] = 0; Table[9, 3] = 0; Table[9, 4] = 0;
        Table[9, 5] = 0; Table[9, 6] = 0; Table[9, 7] = 0; Table[9, 8] = 0; Table[9, 9] = 0;

        // Avion[][]
        //head
        Avion[0, 0] = 0; Avion[0, 1] = 0; Avion[0, 2] = 1; Avion[0, 3] = 0; Avion[0, 4] = 0;
        //wings
        Avion[1, 0] = 1; Avion[1, 1] = 1; Avion[1, 2] = 1; Avion[1, 3] = 1; Avion[1, 4] = 1;
        //mid_1
        Avion[2, 0] = 0; Avion[2, 1] = 0; Avion[2, 2] = 1; Avion[2, 3] = 0; Avion[2, 4] = 0;
        //mid_2
        Avion[3, 0] = 0; Avion[3, 1] = 0; Avion[3, 2] = 1; Avion[3, 3] = 0; Avion[3, 4] = 0;
        //tail
        Avion[4, 0] = 0; Avion[4, 1] = 1; Avion[4, 2] = 1; Avion[4, 3] = 1; Avion[4, 4] = 0;



        // Output Avion[][]
        Console.WriteLine("\nAirplane:\n");
        foreach (var item in Avion)
        {
            counterAvion++;
            Console.Write(item.ToString() + "  ");
            if (counterAvion == 5)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n");
                counterAvion = 0;
            }
        }

        // Output Table[][]
        Console.WriteLine("\nTable:\n");
        Console.WriteLine("  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10\n");
        int counterColumn = 1;
        foreach (var item in Table)
        {
            counterTable++;
            //Console.WriteLine(counterColumn);
            switch (counterColumn)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.Write("A ");
                    break;
                case 12:
                    Console.Write("B ");
                    break;
                case 23:
                    Console.Write("C ");
                    break;
                case 34:
                    Console.Write("D ");
                    break;
                case 45:
                    Console.Write("E ");
                    break;
                case 56:
                    Console.Write("F ");
                    break;
                case 67:
                    Console.Write("G ");
                    break;
                case 78:
                    Console.Write("H ");
                    break;
                case 89:
                    Console.Write("I ");
                    break;
                case 100:
                    Console.Write("J ");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            Console.Write(item.ToString() + "  ");
            if (counterTable == 10)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n");
                counterTable = 0;
                counterColumn++;
            }
            counterColumn++;
        }
Console.ReadLine();
```

I'm new to C#, and so far i like it, but it's.. uhm.. different from the BorlandC I used to play with long time ago.

So, any ideas on how to achieve this?

I'm also aware of the fact that my code so far is kinda messy, so any input on that is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try `Array.Copy()`?

Comment: 1. Values of an array are initialized to zero, so you don't need to specify all of those. 2. Look up "collection initializers" for shorter syntax for initializing the arrays, or better yet, read the initial values from a file. 3. You should extract sections of the behavior you have into methods, rather than throwing everything into one giant `Main`. 4. You don't need a `switch` to write out A-J, just put those letters into a collection an iterate it or hold a counter to the position in it.  5. Try to only include the code you really need to when asking SO questions.

Comment: @tpaksu That would only work if they were the same size.  As is, due to the fact that one is a subset of another in 2D space `Array.Copy` can't handle it (I think).

Comment: I prefer use **Object Oriented Programming**

Comment: well as i said, this is a learning project basically. Thanks for the hints. I am aware of other ways of building that code right there, but this came first on hand as this is my 2nd day in c#

Comment: @tpaksu: also, Array.Copy wouldn't act as an overlay, but would re-write any 1 bits to 0 if they were previously set... this probably isn't what OP wants to do

Comment: @Raika getting there.. nice and easy :)

Comment: I agree with @Raika - this is a bit old school. Create a class Vehicle, with a property Position and a method HitTest(point). This way there won't be clunky array copying and various inheriting classes of Vehicle can probably even forgo the arrays in their definitions

Comment: @StenPetrov my new approach is something between those lines. ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying the values isn't particularly hard.  If you want to create a 3rd array instead you can create a straight copy of the first array at the start and then modify that.

```
public void Combine(int[,] first, int[,] second, int rowStart, int colStart)
{
    //TODO validate parameters, ensure arrays are all large enough, etc.

    for (int i = 0; i < second.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < second.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            first[colStart + i, rowStart + j] |= second[i, j];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This would throw an Index out of bounds exception when one array is smaller than the other. Getting the lengths of both arrays and using the smallest value would do. example : `Math.Min(first.GetLength(0),second.GetLength(0))`

Comment: Double +1 if I could for using `&=` instead of `=` to implement overlay instead of copy!  :)

Comment: Actually, it should be `|=` to overlay.  Gah!

Comment: @Ragnagord As per the comment at the start, I deliberately avoided bounds checking.  It would also be more complex than what you have there when you account for the offset.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Airplane never has dimensions greater than surface, you ca just loop through Airplane and for each index you set surface to the same value.

```
for(int i = 0; i < Airplane.length(0); i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < Airplane.length(1); j++){         
        surface[i,j] = Airplane[i,j]
```

If it's not, you can easily compute what the offset might be.

Comment: That assumes you're always placing the subset in the top left corner.  If you're placing it at an offset you need to account for that.

Comment: That is why i said "If it's not you can easily compute what the offset might be."

Comment: You mention that the Airplane might be larger, what I mean is that the airplane might be smaller, but in the bottom right corner, or shifted down two and to the right one, etc.

Comment: Ah right, didn't think about that. I was just trying to provide a basis for Bigup to work with.